# Django: how to use .filter( ) method in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to display quiz only for users that are registered in a particular course, i.e if a user is registered in a ***Frontend Crash Course*** i want them to see only the `quiz` related to that course they are registered in, and not all the quiz from the db.

i have a model `UserCourse` where i am storing all the courses a user have enrolled in, when i try filtering by that models while `user_course` is `get` like this below

```
user_course = UserCourse.objects.get(user=request.user)
quizzes = Quiz.objects.filter(course__usercourse=user_course).annotate(questions_count=Count('questions'))
```

i get this error `get() returned more than one UserCourse -- it returned 3!`  Now i have changed `.get()` to `.filter()` like this

```
user_course = UserCourse.objects.filter(user=request.user)
quizzes = Quiz.objects.filter(course__usercourse=user_course).annotate(questions_count=Count('questions'))
```

i then get this error `The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.`

What is the right way to write this query.

models.py

```
class UserCourse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usercourse")



class Quiz(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="quizzes")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="quizzes")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user_course = models.ForeignKey(UserCourse, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem in the Second Line

```py
user_course = UserCourse.objects.filter(user=request.user)
quizzes=Quiz.objects.filter(course__usercourse=user_course).annotate(questions_count=Count('questions'))
```

remember that when You are using `filter` you get `QuerySet` not one object
if you want to return the `quizes` those related to `user_course_queryset` you can use `__in` filter

```py
print(user_course) # print it to understand more 
quizzes=Quiz.objects.filter(course__usercourse__in=user_course)
```

this will Return every `Quiz` Related to the `QuerySet` objects

Comment: Not me, But I think this is an easy issue You can Search about it ... Easly